# maven-site: how can I configure the project documentation/information?

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I use the maven site plugin with the fluido-skin. In my site.xml I use

```
<body>
   <menu ref="reports" />
</body>
```

to include the project documentation. However, this gives me:[image: screenshot of menu]

I do not like the indirection from the empty menu entry "project documentation" to "project information" and I do not need all of the project information provided.

So: How can I control the menu structure and content of the referenced reports?